# How to traverse a sorted set in Redis in reverse order using zscan?

Tags: python, redis, iterator, redis-py

I have a sorted set in Redis with priorities starting from 0 up to 3. I would like to traverse this sorted set from highest to lowest priority using the python iterator `zscan_iter`. However, using `zscan_iter` gives me the items starting from 0. Is there a way to reverse the order? Unfortunately, `reverse()` only works on iterators and not on python generators.

I see two solutions:

1. Use negative priorities (so instead of 3 use -3)
2. Paginate through slices of keys using `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`, however I would prefer to use an iterator.

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scanning the Sorted Set with an iterator **does not** guarantee any order. Use `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` for that.